# Implementation of Djikstra doesn't seem to match theoretical complexity

Tags: c++, math, graphics, 3d, graph-theory

I am implementing yet another Djikstra's shortest path algorithm. I have run it on smallish datasets and from what I can tell it is doing things just fine.

The goal is to use this to approximate a geodesic on a mesh. So for example the green line in the following image is an approximation of the geodesic connecting the 2 red points:

[image]

The mesh in that image has 409 vertices and 2304 edges. The asymptotic complexity would give:
409 + 2304 * log(409) \approx 14 000 steps.

My algorithm ran for 830678 steps to compute the solution you see. I know that the actual number of steps won't match the asymptotic notation to the t, but the order of magnitude should be closer. Moreover the runtime of my algorithm seems to increment quite steadily as the input grows. For example for an input where the asymptotic complexity predicted 30 thousand iterations, the algorithm ran for multiple millions of iterations until I killed it (i.e it could have kept going). Almost as if the complexity is running super geometrically or exponentially.

I am trying to see where I messed up so bad that I get the correct outputs (tested) but wrong runtime.

Code:

```
template <typename T>
std::pair<std::vector<uint>, std::vector<double>> Djikstra(
    const std::vector<T>& node_list,
    std::vector<T> (*GetNeighbours)(const T& t),
    uint (*GetId)(const T& t),
    double (*GetDistance)(const T& t1, const T& t2),
    uint start)
{
    std::vector<double> node_distance_map(node_list.size(), std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
    std::vector<uint> node_parent_map(node_list.size());
    std::vector<bool> node_visited_map(node_list.size(), false);

    typedef std::pair<double, uint> NodeInfo;
    std::priority_queue<NodeInfo, std::vector<NodeInfo>, std::greater<NodeInfo>> queue;

    node_distance_map[start] = 0;
    node_parent_map[start] = start;
    queue.push({0, start});

    uint current_node_index = start;
    uint count = 0;
    while(!queue.empty())
    {
        auto[current_distance, current_node_index] = queue.top();
        queue.pop();
        auto current_node = node_list[current_node_index];

        node_visited_map[current_node_index] = true;

        auto neighbours = GetNeighbours(current_node);
        assert(neighbours.size() > 0);
        double shortest_distance = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();
        auto& shortest_neighbour = neighbours[0];
        for(auto& neighbour : neighbours)
        {
            uint neighbour_id = GetId(neighbour);
            // Skip any node that has already been visited
            if(node_visited_map[neighbour_id]) continue;
            double distance = GetDistance(current_node, neighbour);
            double total_distance = distance + current_distance;

            // Overwrite prior distances of the current distance is shorter
            queue.push({total_distance, neighbour_id});
            if(total_distance < node_distance_map[neighbour_id])
            {
                node_parent_map[neighbour_id] = current_node_index;
                node_distance_map[neighbour_id] = total_distance;
            }
        }
        if(count++ % 1'000'000 == 0) std::cout << "At: " << count << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Final: " << count << std::endl;

    return {node_parent_map, node_distance_map};
}
```

EDIT:

This is the DS representing the graph:

```
struct Node
{
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Node> NodePtr;
    uint id;
    vector<std::shared_ptr<Node>> neighbours;
    Eigen::Vector3d position;
};

std::vector<Node::NodePtr> NodeGetNeighbours(const Node::NodePtr& v)
{
    return v->neighbours;
}

uint NodeGetId(const Node::NodePtr& v)
{
    return v->id;
}

double NodeGetDistance(const Node::NodePtr& v1, const Node::NodePtr& v2)
{
    return (v1->position - v2->position).norm();
}
```

Comment: I guess you should find a way to visualize the progress of the algorithm and then check whether it progresses into the right direction. If this is not the case, you have to start debugging.

Comment: I see that GetNeighbors() is a function. How do you get the neighbors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the `queue.push()` statement inside `if`.

```
if (total_distance < node_distance_map[neighbour_id])
{
    node_parent_map[neighbour_id] = current_node_index;
    node_distance_map[neighbour_id] = total_distance;
    queue.push({ total_distance, neighbour_id });
}
```

You'd still get the right answer without doing this, but the size of the priority queue keeps increasing the way you're doing because it's still pushing this new `pair` even if `total_distance >= node_distance_map[neighbour_id]`. Infact to achieve the fastest implementation of Dijkstra, you have to create a priority queue with `decreasePriority` method. But for that it is required to know the `index` in the queue where the object is stored of which you wish to decrease priority of. That way you're guaranteed not to have more than `N` nodes in the priority queue.

Comment: Does the STL have a way to do this kind of in place priority update or would i have to make my own?

Comment: @Makogan the container you pass to `priority_queue` is `protected`, so you can do something with than. But most likely you'll have to implement it on your own.

Comment: MAN the difference one line of code makes!, it passed from doing millions upon millions of iterations to just a couple thousand. Remarkable.

Comment: In retrsopect it makes perfect sense the other implementation was pushing each vertex for every other vertex, qhich is quadratic.

Comment: `log(N^2) = 2*log(N)` is still `O(log(N))`. And there can't be more than `N^2` elements in the queue as there can be at max `N^2` edges in a graph (unless it's a multi-edge graph). I think the problem lies with the `vector` passed to the priority queue. It might be getting reallocated multiple times taking `O(N)` time. Try reserving `N^2` size for that vector and try your code from above. It should be fast.

Comment: Ahh wait... I see the `while` loop runs until queue is not empty. Then you're right. It becomes quadratic. In fact you can put a counter on the loop. The first `N` elements you pop from the queue are your `N` nodes. You can break the loop after that.